# ErrorException Trying to access array offset on value of type null (View: I:\Laravel Project\EcomLaravelProject\resources\views\header.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

This is my Laravel **ProductController** files function:

```
static function cartItem()
 {
        $userId=Session::get('user')['id'];
        return Cart::where('user_id',$userId)->count();
    }
```

And here is my **header.blade.php** file where i using **ProductController.php** files **cartItem()** functions property but i am unable to solve :

```
 <?php 
 use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;
 $total=ProductController::cartItem(null);
?>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Brand
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Order</a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item navbar-right" >
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">cart({{$total}})</a>
</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

> "ErrorException Trying to access array offset on value of type null
> (View: I:\Laravel
> Project\EcomLaravelProject\resources\views\header.blade.php)"

Comment: May be it should be `$userId=Session::get('user');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if your session doesn't have a `user` data.

```php
Session::get('user'); //returns null if the session doesn't have user data

//so 

Session::get('user')['id']; //Trying to access array offset on value of type null

//it is like writing 

null['id']; //Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

There is no "right" solution here, the easiest would be to check if `user` exists in the session before doing anythiing else.

```php
static function cartItem()
{
    $user = Session::get('user');
   
    if($user == null){
        return 0;
    }

    return Cart::where('user_id',$user['id'])->count();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your user session is null so you can't get the id, you have to check first if the session has user, you can write it in this way:

```
if (Session::has('users')) {
  $user=Session::get('user');
  return Cart::where('user_id',$user->id)->count();
}
```

Comment: This solution  is solve my error but not actually problem. But thank a lot for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

For **Laravel 4.0** , use:

```
$userId = session_id();
```

For **Laravel 4.1 and versions above Laravel 4.1.** , use :

```
$userId = Session::getId();
```

For **Laravel 5.5** , add `use Session`, then :

```
$userId = session()->getId();
```